# installed package with snap - command not available

Tags: apt, package-management, ubuntu-core, tmux, snap

I saw that `tmux` is available with `snap find` and `apt-cache`. I decided to install with `snap`. Howto use now `tmux`?

I am normal desktop user, not cloud computing.

```
# snap 
error: Please specify one command of: abort, ack, changes, connect, disconnect, find, install, interfaces, known, list, login, logout, refresh or remove
# snap install tmux
428.00 KB / 428.00 KB [============================================================================================] 100.00 % 452.28 KB/s 

# tmux new
The program 'tmux' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install tmux
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed a bug in current snap integration on desktop.
The binary wrapper is generated, but not in $PATH: `/snap/bin/tmux`.

Do you mind opening a bug against the snappy package on launchpad? https://launchpad.net/snappy Thanks a lot!

Comment: thank there is already a bug report and it got fixed "/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh comment talks about /snaps/bin (which doesn't exist) when in reality it uses /snap/bin" https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1569892